# Is there any difference between uintptr_t and unsigned int when unsigned int can hold any address?

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer

Description of `uintptr_t`:

> The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the
>   property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type,
>   then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare
>   equal to the original pointer:
>
> uintptr_t

And since any pointer can be converted to void pointer and vice versa:

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object
>   type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to
>   void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original
>   pointer.

Any pointer can be converted to `uintptr_t` and vice versa, OK.

Now, description of integers and pointers:

[`Integer -> Pointer`]

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously
>   specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be
>   correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced
>   type, and might be a trap representation

[`Pointer -> Integer`]

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as
>   previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the
>   result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is
>   undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any
>   integer type.

OK. Now, since in my system's ABI (Procedure call standard for ARM architecture) both unsigned int and pointers have same size and alignment, and my system uses plain 32bit continuous values starting from `0x0` for memory addresses, it seems that the implementation-defined gap in the conversion of

`Integer -> Pointer` and `Pointer -> Integer`

has been filled in my system, and I can safely convert pointers to unsigned integers, and there is no difference between converting a pointer into `uintptr_t` and converting a pointer to `unsigned int` in my system (both will yield same value). Am I right with my assumption? or there is something I'm missing?

Comment: Take a look at `stdint.h` and see how `uintptr_t` is defined.

Comment: The size of uintptr_t changes depending on your architecture. It is the same size as a pointer on whichever architecture you are running.

Comment: Given there is a type intended for use in treating pointers as integers, why do you not want to use it?

Comment: @EricPostpischil `uintptr_t` is optional [c11 7.20.1.4], and also for learning purpose

Comment: "And since any pointer can be converted to void pointer and vice versa:" --> No.  Counter examples: function pointers and pointers to objects with a small width than `void*`.  What can be done is any object pointer to `void *` and back to an equivalent object pointer.

Comment: @chux "and pointers to objects with a small width than `void*`" can you please give an example? I don't follow

Comment: @user2162550 Example: an `int *` may be `N` bit and a `void *` is `2N` bit.  An `int *` may be saved sufficiently in a `void *`, but not visa-versa.  C supports many memory layouts.  See C17 §6.2.5 28 "Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even given that `unsigned int` has enough bits to represent all addresses in the C implementation, the C standard does not guarantee this means that, given a `void *` pointer `p`, the expression `(void *) (unsigned) p == p` evaluates to true. Because the conversion from `void *` to an integer is implementation-defined, it might do more than simply reproduce the address as an `unsigned` value. It might include some bits describing the provenance of the address or a checksum, and `unsigned` might be insufficient to contain the necessary information to restore the original value.

Most implementations are likely to simply convert the address in the obvious way, reinterpreting the bits of the virtual memory adddress as an `unsigned` value, and no problems will arise. However, this is a feature of the implementation; it is not a requirement of the C standard.

Comment: is this different between `unsigned int` and `uintptr_t`? I think your answer applies to pointer conversion of both types (converting a pointer to `unsigned int` and converting a pointer to `uintptr_t`), while I'm looking to see if there is a difference between them.

Comment: @user2162550: The standard says `uintptr_t` is defined so that the property `(void *) (uintptr_t) p == p` is satisfied. It does not say that for `unsigned int`. A C implementation with 32-bit addresses might nonetheless define `uintptr_t` as a 64-bit type so that it can include provenance information, and it might let `(void *) (unsigned) p == p` fail.

Comment: you are right. Also, do you think that the word `may` in pointer to integer conversion `Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type` is also a thing here? because `may` is weaker than `uintptr_t` convertion description `any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type`? I'm asking because I'm not an english native

Comment: Also, if I'm only interested in pointer to integer conversion, without converting back to a pointer, do you still think there is a difference? because `(void *) (uintptr_t) p == p` is not relevant when I'm only taking `(uintptr_t) p`. So is there a difference between `(uintptr_t) p` and `(unsigned int) p` in my described system ?

Comment: @user2162550: The “may” in that context is saying the program may do this, and the behavior provided by the C implementation will get the job done. So it is a definite specification about how the C implementation behaves.

Comment: @user2162550: As with the round trip, the C standard does not guarantee the results of the one-way conversion: It is implementation-defined. Most implementations will behave simply. But, as a matter of what the C standard says, it does not guarantee the results.